# Spark-2.3 submit not working for one master one slave confifuration in Windows 10 -64bit

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark-standalone

Following steps for Hadoop hdfs and spark:-

1) **Environment variables** -

- **HADOOP_CONF_DIR -**    F:\spark\Hadoop2\hadoop-2.7.6\etc\hadoop
- **HADOOP_HOME -**    F:\spark\Hadoop2\hadoop-2.7.6
- **JAVA_HOME -**  F:\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
- **SPARK_HOME -** F:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7

Path:

- F:\spark\Hadoop2\hadoop-2.7.6\bin
- F:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin
- F:\spark\Hadoop2\hadoop-2.7.6\lib\native

2) **core-site.xml**

[image]

3) **hdfs-site.xml**

[image]

4) **mapred-site.xml**

[image]

**Command to start master** -

- spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master

**Command to start one worker**-

- spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://192.168.0.12:7077

**To submit job**

- spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master spark://192.168.0.12:7077 F:/spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.0.jar

**Error log** -

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: F
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getHadoopFileSystem(Utils.scala:1893)
>           at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:690)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.downloadFile(DependencyUtils.scala:131)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:401)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:401)
>           at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:400)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
>           at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

I am not able to resolve the issue even after trying several blogs.